# Rails: Filter ActiveRecord Search Results using Checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to build a checkbox filter which will reduce the number of results with each box checked. Each checked box will represent a has_many: through association.

I have an app with three models:
Book
Subject
BookSubject

They are associated like so:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :book_subjects
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_subjects
  has_many :books, through: :book_subjects
end

class BookSubject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

Through the Books controller, the user can run the Search action, which renders a view page with all of the books shown. By checking boxes in the sidebar (each of which is labeled with the name of a subject), the user should be able to narrow down the number of books which fit their search. This is the search action so far:

```
def search
  if params[:name].nil? || params[:name].empty?
    @all_books = Book.all
  else
    @all_books = Book.joins(:subjects).where(subjects: {name: params[:name].split(",")}).distinct
  end
  render 'search'
end
```

Right now, if the user selects "historical" and "epic", they get all books with historical as a subject, and all books with epic as a subject. I would like them to get ONLY the books with both historical AND epic as a subject. I've tried adding .group to the query, but so far it's not working:

```
def search
  if params[:name].nil? || params[:name].empty?
    @all_books = Book.all
  else
    @all_books = Book.joins(:subjects)
      .where(subjects: {name: params[:name].split(",")})
      .group("books.id")
      .having("count(*) >= ?", 1)
    end
  end
end
```

How should I modify my query to make filtering possible? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is almost fine but why do you have `having("count(*) >= ?", 1)`?
That condition matches for books which have only one subject from all required list.
Try to change code to the following

```
def search
  @all_books = if params[:name].blank?
    Book.all
  else
    names = params[:name].split(',')
    Book.joins(:subjects)
        .where(subjects: { name: names })
        .group(:id)
        .having('count(*) = ?', names.size)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the names = params[:name].split(',') line - that was what was missing for me to grab the names.size (for the count line). It's still not filtering, however - when I check 'historical' and 'epic' I'm still getting everything historical and everything epic, when I want only the historical epics. Any thoughts?

Comment: Very strange. Can you provide exact SQL that it generates? You can see it server log.

Comment: Sure thing! With one box checked: Book Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "book_subjects" ON "book_subjects"."book_id" = "books"."id" INNER JOIN "subjects" ON "subjects"."id" = "book_subjects"."subject_id" WHERE "subjects"."name" = 'epic/saga' GROUP BY books.id HAVING count(*) >= 1

Comment: With two boxes checked: Book Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "book_subjects" ON "book_subjects"."book_id" = "books"."id" INNER JOIN "subjects" ON "subjects"."id" = "book_subjects"."subject_id" WHERE "subjects"."name" IN ('epic/saga', 'family') GROUP BY books.id HAVING count(*) >= 2      BUT this returns the same number of books.

Comment: Why is it still `>=`? In my answer it is just `=`. Please try it once again.

Comment: When I use just `=` the filtering doesn't work - checking one box returns 0 books `Book Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "book_subjects" ON "book_subjects"."book_id" = "books"."id" INNER JOIN "subjects" ON "subjects"."id" = "book_subjects"."subject_id" WHERE "subjects"."name" = 'epic/saga' GROUP BY "books"."id" HAVING count(*) = 1` Since every book has many subjects, I want the query to return any book whose subjects array contains all of the query parameters.

Comment: Claudia for me everything works fine. In fact `>=` and `=` work just the same since `where` filter out records with different subject names. Please check your data and try it again.

Comment: You can try to test pure SQL by running `rails dbconsole` and executting statements above.

Comment: I have tried it with both `>=` and `=`, and got the same results. I also tried it in the rails console and am still getting the same results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Precisely. I'm not sure what is going on here. I guess for now I'm going to work on other features of the app, and come back to this in a day or two and see if I can get some fresh perspective, because I (and everyone I've asked) am completely stumped. Thank you so much for your help with this -  your input definitely made a difference. :)

Comment: Not at all. Just know that it all works for me =). You can leave a comment here and I will be right here to finally resolve the question!